# rename ubuntu 20.04 hostname to `new_master_1` results in hostname `newmaster1`

Tags: 20.04

I rename the host nmae in both `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`(the name after 127.0.0.1) to `new_master_1` but the host name is `newmaster1`.

Is `_` invalid ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. [This wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname) goes into greater detail. Be sure to look at the section on restrictions:

> Hostnames are composed of series of labels concatenated with dots, as are all domain names. For example, "en.wikipedia.org" is a hostname. Each label must be between 1 and 63 characters long, and the entire hostname (including the delimiting dots but not a trailing dot) has a maximum of 253 ASCII characters.
>
> The Internet standards (Requests for Comments) for protocols mandate that component hostname labels may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (in a case-insensitive manner), the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen ('-'). The original specification of hostnames in [RFC 952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952), mandated that labels could not start with a digit or with a hyphen, and must not end with a hyphen. However, a subsequent specification ([RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123)) permitted hostname labels to start with digits. No other symbols, punctuation characters, or white space are permitted.

Letters A to Z with numbers and dashes only

Comment: Thanks. `.` is also invalid, `new.master.1` results in `new`.